# AngularJS and ExpressJS: how to read content sent by $http.put()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have problem with angularJS application, which sends callbacks to nodejs server. When I use POST or GET methods, all works fine, however when I send PUT request, I get error.

If I call the server from `curl`, It works fine; when I call some remote server from angularJS using PUT method, it also works all right. So the problem lies in cooperation between angularJS and nodejs on my localhost, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

My angular method, calling local nodejs server:

```
 $http({
   method  :'PUT',
     url:'http://127.0.0.1:3000/s',
     data: $.param({"test":true, _method: 'PUT'}),
     headers :{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('OK');
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert('catch' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

My nodejs file:

```
var express        =    require("express");
var mysql          =    require('mysql');
var bodyParser     =    require('body-parser')
var methodOverride =    require('method-override');
var app            =    express();

//use body parser to get json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// allow PUT from browser
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.put('/s', function(req, res){
  console.log('OK');
  //handle_database_put(req, res);
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.send('PUT OK');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**EDIT** Here is the error message in Angular app. The server never print `OK` as it should

```
{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/s","data":"test=true&_method=PUT","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

**EDIT 2**: I have just noticed, that the request is not recognized as `PUT`, but as `OPTIONS`

Comment: I have not used Node.js and I get the same issue.I've replaced by POST. I'd like to know why this happens.

Comment: You are defining URL params to send with your put request but trying to retrieve the data from req.query. Have you tried just sending {test: true} without it being wrapped in $param() ?

Comment: `req.query`? check what is delivered in `req.body`

Comment: that does not matter, the server never "acknowledges" that it received request from angular and does not print anything (I can change it to ```console.log('OK')```, but it does not print anything). The error is returned to angular app, but the server does not seem to even get the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the problem:

What happens is, that the browser makes a preflight `OPTIONS` HTTP request, and if it receives status 200 from server, than in proceeds to the original PUT call.

On the ExpressJS server, following configuration were made and the PUT request from AngularJS is now correctly sending and receiving data using PUT request:

```
// apply this rule to all requests accessing any URL/URI
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // add details of what is allowed in HTTP request headers to the response headers
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    // the next() function continues execution and will move onto the requested URL/URI
    next();
});
```

It is still a mystery to me, why `POST` request were correctly processed and `PUT` requests were not

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$http({
   method  :'PUT',
     url:'http://127.0.0.1:3000/s',
     params: {"test":true, _method: 'PUT'},
     headers :{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('OK');
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert('catch' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

Comment: not working. I think the json data must be url-encoded, and my code works perfectly with POST method. The issue arises when I change the method, but everything else remains the same

Comment: Why are you using `content-type` : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051730/angular-http-post-returnd-empty-error

Answer (score 0):

Your server `"Accept":"application/json` and you are sending `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` so you must use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and transform your data to json, like this:

```
function youMethod(){
            var myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/s';

            var data = {
                test: true,
                _method: "PUT"
            };

            return $http({
                url: myUrl,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: JSON.stringify(data), 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
              }).then(youMethodComplete)
                .catch(youMethodFailed);

            function youMethodComplete(response) {
                alert('OK');
                console.log(response);
            }

            function uyouMethodFailed(response) {
                alert('ERROR');
                console.log(response);     
            }
        }
```

pd: I recommend too -> [don't use $http success](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)

Extra: If you want use `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and you configure your server for this purpose and you want to follow this syntax:

```
function youMethod(){
                var myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/s';

                var data = {
                    test: true,
                    _method: "PUT"
                };

                return $http({
                    url: myUrl,
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: $httpParamSerializer(data), //remember to inject $httpParamSerializer
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                  }).then(youMethodComplete)
                    .catch(youMethodFailed);

                function youMethodComplete(response) {
                    alert('OK');
                    console.log(response);
                }

                function uyouMethodFailed(response) {
                    alert('ERROR');
                    console.log(response);     
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code (sending Application/JSON) results in error: {"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/s","data":"{\"test\":true,\"_method\":\"PUT\"}","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}, which is why I was using application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: And also the method using x-www-form-urlencoded returns error: {"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/s","data":"_method=PUT&test=true","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}