# Input form data using Angularjs, Expressjs,

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm a beginner having a bit of a problem.  I can't seem to pass the text from my form into the subsequent req.body that I'm supposed to get using body-parser.  There are multiple questions on the subject, but so far none seem to be of help.  please guide me in the right direction. MODS PLEASE DO NOT LOCK. I have searched and could find a suitable answer.  Thank you.

Express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended' : 'true'}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());




app.post('/', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.text);
        res.redirect('https://google.com');
        res.end();
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('application', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http.post('/', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
                <div class="form-group">


                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="email" ng-model="formData.text">
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-submit="submitForm()">Add</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: have you intercepted the `post` call? it looks like there's no actual URL

Comment: Please explain.  I wasn't aware that I needed one.  I thought a "/" would do

Comment: I have now changed the URL and am getting a 404 cannot POST/ error

Comment: you have a local nodeJS server and an angular app, you need the app to send an `$http` call to the server. figure out the server location (start with its port)

Comment: look at an example of a server URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135444/angularjs-and-expressjs-how-to-read-content-sent-by-http-put

Comment: I added port 8080 to my post request.  However the req.body.text is still showing as undefined on my console.  Its not displaying the raw text like I feel like it should be.  Thanks for the help btw

Comment: When you enter `submitForm`, place a `console.log($scope.formData)`, let's see the output first

Comment: I'm getting an empty set {} when I log ($scope.formData) into the console.  $scope.formData.text is giving me an undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently sending no object `text` to your server, you're sending a `formData` object containing a `text` property.

You can try:

```
console.log(req.body.formData.text);
```

Then if you want to retrieve some data inside angular, you have to send data back:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.formData.text);
    res.send("blablabla");
```

or

```
res.json({response: 'response'});
```

Comment: This doesn't work but it might help.  When I log(req.body.formData.text) I get a 500 server typeerror altogether. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Stephen\Dropbox\apps\serverv1\server.js:27:34