# Angular JS: http.post is returning null in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm making an ajax call from Angular JS:

```
var response = $http.post(
    '/services/login/?_nochache='+new Date().getTime(),      
    JSON.stringify(credentials)
);
```

I'm adding the `_nocache` setting, thinking that maybe some cache or something like that.

I'm also converting the object `credentials` into string thinking that Internet Explorer could not recognise the object.

I'm really lost here, In chrome the call works perfectly, in IE 10, the response of the service is null.

What can be causing this?

### EDIT

The service is **returning 401**, which is ok, since the user is wrong, but the response should be (as is in other browsers), the error string saying the user is wrong, in this case is null.

I'm using the promise like this:

```
promise.then(onLoginOk, onLoginError);
...

function onLoginError(response) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

The console returns

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "http://dev.site.com:8000/api/auth/login/",
    "data": {
      "username": "mail@domain.com",
      "password": "password"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

### EDIT

Here is the Response body I get in IE.
[image]

These are the headers I get with the `401` which is correct, but the response body is wrong.
[image]

Comment: how are you using the promise response? please post code.

Comment: Did it reach the backend service (`services/login`) when you use `IE10`?

Comment: I guess if didn't reach the backend I wouldn't have a 401 right?

Comment: Have you tried with $httpParamSerializerJQLike ? I had a similar issue some days, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Comment: I have the same error :/

Comment: Could you try to change the document mode with `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >` and test again?

Comment: did you go through with this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051730/angular-http-post-returnd-empty-error

Comment: What is the target IE version ?

Comment: You don't have to convert the post object into JSON, your back-end will have troubles to deserialize it (or you do it manually).
Can you check in the debug-tools of IE what the server responded in the http request, do not check in JS, check at the source to see if the server really responded with a null data

Comment: @HiDeo This just act as IE9, And Adds a popup saying the browser is not supported. Wont work

Comment: @BiswajitPanday I have tried, seems the backend does not support this kind of post. I get a 500 in all browsers

Comment: @Titmael is IE10+. I'm trying to post an object and string and both fail

Comment: @Pablo can you check the raw answer from the server in the debug tools of IE ?

Comment: @Titmael The response is empty, I'll attach a picture in a moment

Comment: I have just edited adding the pictures

Comment: ok, can you debug your server to check what response it sends ?

Comment: I cannot, but if there was an issue there, I wont get the 401 as I get in other browsers. Maybe this is the issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785990/ie-10-on-win8-does-not-assign-the-correct-status-to-xmlhttprequest-when-the-result-is-401

I guess I should ask to change the 401 to other status code.

Comment: @Pablo is it happening in an intranet zone?

Comment: No, It's happening in my local machine

Comment: Do you have the same issue using something like postman.https://www.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 1):

This seems like same problem of mine.

In my case, my request function works well in every browser except MS Edge.

I tried to find solution or reason, and finally I got one.

Some answers suggested adding tags like

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
```

or adding code into `config` like

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
// extra
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

but these couldn't solve my problem.

Finally I saw one answer said this may occurred by a kind of policy handling caches in Edge.

This can occur when I use local server to send requests or get responses.

And it will gonna disappear when test on other server not on local.

I hope your problem is same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of stretch, please don't go nuts if I am wrong here.  Don't have the rep points to comment.

Have you looked into this article?
[Error 401 and 403 only in Internet Explorer (not in Chrome, Firefox, ..) - IIS configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526579/error-401-and-403-only-in-internet-explorer-not-in-chrome-firefox-iis-c)

Comment: It looks like you are having an authorization issue and IE is the target of the authorization blocker.